# Why .dll creation date changes when moving to another pc

Tags: c#, windows

I compiled project, and `.dll` file has creation date equal to date when project was built.

I moved this file to another pc, and creation date changes. Why?
[image]

Comment: Is it reflecting the date/time set on the other PC? Technically you did create a new file there, so the fact that it changes isn't surprising to me, the fact that it's Aug 2015 is (possibly) surprising.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb the .dll is used from package http://restsharp.org/. Maybe that is the point. Technically I did not created new .dll - I used existing one.

Comment: No, I'm saying the act of copying the .dll itself is creating a new file on PC 2.

Comment: The creation date is metadata in the filesystem. It has nothing to do with the internal data of the file. In particular, for an EXE or DLL, it has nothing to do with the image [build timestamp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ns-winnt-_image_file_header).